# AdMob import cannot be resolved

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to get AdMob working with my android app and I'm having some trouble. I've changed the target sdk to 15 in both the manifest and in project.properties and I've declared the AdActivity in the manifest, but it is still not recognizing the import com.google.ads.* in my activity. How can I get this to work?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app.firstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/blue_ship"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.app.firstapp.StartGame"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>/> 
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: are you using eclipse or ant? in eclipse you have to add admob jar to your build path, in ant you have to put it into lib directory under your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set target as Google API's, And need to add Admob sdk lib/jar instead of Android target.

1) Right Click on Project> Properties >Android > Project Build Target.

from target window choose Google Api's(Vendor name is Google inc there)

2) Add admob sdk lib in your project via Config build path option,

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the admob sdk in libs folder of your project??

Also need to add in build path.

Do the above steps, your problem will be solved

Comment: I have the file GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.1.0.jar in my libs folder and I added it to my build path, but its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow all steps of this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals) and select the build target of your proyect properly.

Answer (score 0):

Very frustrating but just cleaning the project solved this problem.